# Objects don't cast shadows on other objects

Tags: c, opengl, shadows

I made a OpenGL program with GLEW and GLFW on Orwell Dev-C++ 5.4.0 which shows blocks. I added ambient, diffuse and specular light and now shadows, too. I used a depth texture. But now, the blocks don't cast shadows on other blocks, rather only on themselves!

This is the important part of my source code:

```
void createShadows()
{
    int error;

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &buffers.depthFbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, buffers.depthFbo);

    glGenTextures(1, &buffers.depthTbo);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, buffers.depthTbo);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, winInfo.winWidth, winInfo.winHeight, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, buffers.depthTbo, 0);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);

    error = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if(error != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        printError("FramebufferError.txt", "Framebuffer", error);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}

void init()
{
    renderProg = compileShaders("openglSuperTutorials12.vss", "openglSuperTutorials12.fss", 0);
    renderProgDepth = compileShaders("openglSuperTutorials12_depth.vss", "openglSuperTutorials12_depth.fss", 0);

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &buffers.vao);
    glBindVertexArray(buffers.vao);

    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);

    matrices.mMatrixDepth                    = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    matrices.pMatrixDepth                    = glm::ortho(-10.0f, 10.0f, -10.0f, 10.0f, -10.0f, 20.0f);
    matrices.biasMatrixDepth                 = glm::mat4(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                                         0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                                         0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
                                                         0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);

    //Initialize light and material properties and give them to the "renderProg" (truncated)

    glfwGetWindowSize(window, &winInfo.winWidth, &winInfo.winHeight);
    glfwSetCursorPos(window, winInfo.winWidth/2.0, winInfo.winHeight/2.0);

    createTexture();
    createVertices();
    createBlocks();
    createShadows();
}

void setBlock(glm::vec3 position, int id, int depth)
{
    if(depth != 1)
    {
        matrices.mMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), position);
        matrices.mvpMatrixBiasDepth = matrices.biasMatrixDepth * matrices.mvpMatrixDepth;

        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(renderProg, "mMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, &matrices.mMatrix[0][0]);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(renderProg, "mvpMatrixBiasDepth"), 1, GL_FALSE, &matrices.mvpMatrixBiasDepth[0][0]);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, buffers.tbo);
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(renderProg, "texBlock"), 0);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, buffers.depthTbo);
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(renderProg, "shadowMap"), 1);

        glGenBuffers(1, &buffers.tcbo);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.tcbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(blocks[id]), blocks[id], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    }
    else
    {
        matrices.mvpMatrixDepth = matrices.pMatrixDepth * matrices.vMatrixDepth * matrices.mMatrixDepth;
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(renderProgDepth, "mvpMatrixDepth"), 1, GL_FALSE, &matrices.mvpMatrixDepth[0][0]);
    }

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

    if(depth != 1)
    {
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &buffers.tcbo);
    }
}

void display()
{
    int x, y, z;

    GLfloat bgColor[] = { 0.0f, 0.73f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat depthOne = 1.0f;

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, buffers.depthFbo);
    glClearBufferfv(GL_DEPTH, 0, &depthOne);
    glUseProgram(renderProgDepth);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);

    if(viewPos.lightSticky == 1)
    {
        lightProperties.lightPosition  = glm::vec3(viewPos.eyeX, viewPos.eyeY, viewPos.eyeZ);
        lightProperties.lightDirection = glm::vec3(viewPos.centerX, viewPos.centerY, viewPos.centerZ);
    }

    matrices.vMatrixDepth = glm::lookAt(
                    lightProperties.lightPosition,
                    lightProperties.lightDirection,
                    glm::vec3(viewPos.upX, viewPos.upY, viewPos.upZ));

    for(z=-5; z<=5; z++)
    {
        for(y=0; y<=6; y++)
        {
            for(x=-5; x<=5; x++)
            {
                if(blockMap[z+5][y][x+5].id != -1)
                    setBlock(blockMap[z+5][y][x+5].position, blockMap[z+5][y][x+5].id, 1);
            }
        }
    }



    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, bgColor);
    glClearBufferfv(GL_DEPTH, 0, &depthOne);
    glUseProgram(renderProg);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    lightProperties.cameraPosition = glm::vec3(viewPos.eyeX, viewPos.eyeY, viewPos.eyeZ);

    matrices.vMatrix = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(viewPos.eyeX, viewPos.eyeY, viewPos.eyeZ),
                                   glm::vec3(viewPos.centerX, viewPos.centerY, viewPos.centerZ),
                                   glm::vec3(viewPos.upX, viewPos.upY, viewPos.upZ));
    matrices.pMatrix = glm::perspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)winInfo.winWidth/(GLfloat)winInfo.winHeight, 0.1f, 1000.0f);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(renderProg, "vMatrix"),                1, GL_FALSE, &matrices.vMatrix[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(renderProg, "pMatrix"),                1, GL_FALSE, &matrices.pMatrix[0][0]);

    //Update light uniforms (truncated)

    for(z=-5; z<=5; z++)
    {
        for(y=0; y<=6; y++)
        {
            for(x=-5; x<=5; x++)
            {
                if(blockMap[z+5][y][x+5].id != -1)
                    setBlock(blockMap[z+5][y][x+5].position, blockMap[z+5][y][x+5].id, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    winInfo.frames++;
}
```

The Vertex-Shader "openglSuperTutorials12.vss":

```
#version 430 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 vPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 vTexCoord;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 vNormal;

out vec3 fPosition;
out vec4 fShadowCoord;
out vec2 fTexCoord;
out vec3 fNormal;

uniform mat4 mMatrix;
uniform mat4 vMatrix;
uniform mat4 pMatrix;
uniform mat4 mvpMatrixBiasDepth;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = pMatrix * vMatrix * mMatrix * vec4(vPosition, 1.0);
    fPosition = vPosition;
    fShadowCoord = mvpMatrixBiasDepth * vec4(vPosition, 1.0);
    fTexCoord = vTexCoord;
    fNormal = normalize(transpose(inverse(mat3(mMatrix))) * vNormal);
}
```

The Fragment-Shader "openglSuperTutorials12.fss":

```
#version 430 core

in vec3 fPosition;
in vec4 fShadowCoord;
in vec2 fTexCoord;
in vec3 fNormal;

out vec4 outColor;

uniform sampler2D texBlock;
uniform sampler2D shadowMap;
uniform mat4 mMatrix;

uniform int   ambientLightEnabled;
uniform int   diffuseLightEnabled;
uniform int   specularLightEnabled;
uniform int   shadowsEnabled;
uniform vec3  ambientLightColor;
uniform vec3  diffuseLightColor;
uniform vec3  specularLightColor;
uniform vec3  lightPosition;
uniform vec3  cameraPosition;
uniform float lightAttenuation;
uniform vec3  spotlightConeDirection;
uniform float spotlightCosCutoff;
uniform float spotlightExponent;

uniform vec3  ambientMaterialColor;
uniform vec3  diffuseMaterialColor;
uniform vec3  specularMaterialColor;
uniform float shininess;
uniform float strength;

void main()
{
    vec3  shadowValue = vec3(textureProj(shadowMap, fShadowCoord));
    vec3  surfacePos = vec3(mMatrix * vec4(fPosition, 1.0));
    vec3  surfaceToLight = normalize(lightPosition - surfacePos);
    vec3  surfaceToCamera = normalize(cameraPosition - surfacePos);

    vec3  ambientColor = ambientMaterialColor * ambientLightColor;

    float diffuseIntensity = max(0.0, dot(fNormal, surfaceToLight));
    vec3  diffuseColor = diffuseIntensity * diffuseLightColor * diffuseMaterialColor;

    float specularIntensity;
    if(diffuseIntensity == 0.0)
        specularIntensity = 0.0;
    else
        specularIntensity = pow(max(0.0, dot(fNormal, normalize(surfaceToLight + surfaceToCamera))), shininess) * strength;
    vec3  specularColor = specularIntensity * specularLightColor * specularMaterialColor;

    float distanceToLight = length(surfacePos - lightPosition);
    float attenuation = 1.0 / (
                    lightAttenuation +
                    lightAttenuation * distanceToLight + 
                    lightAttenuation * distanceToLight * distanceToLight);

    vec3  lightColorCombined = vec3(0.0);
    if(ambientLightEnabled == 1)
    {
        lightColorCombined += ambientColor;
    }
    if(diffuseLightEnabled == 1)
    {
        if(shadowsEnabled == 1)
            diffuseColor *= shadowValue;
        lightColorCombined += diffuseColor;
    }
    if(specularLightEnabled == 1)
    {
        if(shadowsEnabled == 1)
            specularColor *= shadowValue;
        lightColorCombined += attenuation * specularColor;
    }

    outColor = texture(texBlock, fTexCoord) * vec4(lightColorCombined, 1.0);   
}
```

The other shaders ("openglSuperTutorials12_depth.vss" and "openglSuperTutorials12_depth.fss") are only simple pass-through shaders with the "mvpMatrixDepth".

[A screenshot of the scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yf8qq.png)

What do I have to change to let the light cast shadows on other objects?

Comment: In general it is always helpful to render the shadow map as a texture on the screen. (Note that depending on the way you generated it, it is not linear, so you might need to place your light source very close to the caster in order to see nice contours).

Comment: It wouldn't be particularly helpful in this case. Texture comparison needs to be disabled and `sampler2DShadow` needs to be replaced with `sampler2D` or it is going to test the stored depth against the R-component (as in s,t,r) of the texture coordinates rather than returning the actual depth.

Comment: OK, I edited the code like you said, but the result is still similar (only the bad jaggies disappeared)! I updated the screenshot, too. Do you know another solution?